# Initialize a class in BeforeTestRun hook and use it in BeforeScenario

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow

I am using extent Reports in my specflow unit tests.
I have 2 projects in 1 solution. I have a separate project for creating a hook file which will be common for both the projects.
I need to initialize my extentreports object in `BeforeTestRun` hook and use it in `BeforeScenario`.
I am not getting a way to access the same.
Here is my code so far :

```
 public static void BeforeFeature()
    {
        extentReports = new ExtentReports();

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title + ".html");

        htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = Theme.Dark;

        extentReports.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
        TestcaseConst._logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        FeatureContext.Current.Set<ExtentReports>(extentReports);
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public static void BeforeScenario()
    {
        extentTest = FeatureContext.Current.Get<ExtentReports>().CreateTest(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title, "This test is to check the status of API under test");
        ScenarioContext.Current.Set<ExtentTest>(extentTest);
    }
```

Now, I need to shift this code under BeforeFeature to BeforeTestRun, but I am not getting to save something like this   "FeatureContext.Current.Set(extentReports);" in BeforeTestRun.

Please help if anyone knows.
Thanks In Advance.